# Assignment to empty index (empty square brackets x[]<-) on LHS

Tags: r, syntax, casting, variable-assignment, reshape

While looking at an answer posted recently on SO, I noticed an unfamiliar assignment statement. Instead of the usual form of  `myVar<- myValue`, it used the form `myVar[]<- myValue`, i.e. the object on lefthand side is indexed with empty square brackets. Personally, I had never seen such an assignment, but it had a highly useful effect-- it reshaped the assigned data 'myValue' to the shape of 'myVar'.

I would like to use this in my code as this makes things lot easier. However the documentation for `"<-"` seems to be silent on it.

Is this a well established feature and one can rely on it to work in all cases?

Also, my guess is that it might be a side effect of a function call stack, i.e. calling `<-` and `[` in sequence, but I could not figure out how. Can someone throw some light on that?

Here's an example--

```
# A dataframe
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 11:14)

# simple assignment assigns to class of RHS
df1 <- c(21:24, 31:34)
df1 
#[1] 21 22 23 24 31 32 33 34
class(df1)
#[1] "integer"

#assignment with [] casts to class of LHS 
df1<- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 11:14)
df1[]<- c(21:24,31:34)
df1

#    a  b
# 1 21 31
# 2 22 32
# 3 23 33
# 4 24 34


# recycling to preserve shape
df1[]<- c(101:102)
df1

#     a   b
# 1 101 101
# 2 102 102
# 3 101 101
# 4 102 102

class(df1)
#data.frame

# reshaping 

df1<- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 11:14)
df1[] <- matrix(1:8, 2,4)
df1 #matrix reshaped 
class(df1)
#[1] "data.frame"

# flattening 
x<- 1:8
x[] <- matrix(1:8,4,2)
x
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Some hints: check out `?Extract` and try running `'[<-'(df1,,,8:1)`

Comment: @joran : yes.. that seems to be where i should have looked. Many thanks. I'd look at it and revert tomorrow . well past late here..

Comment: You can dig out the logic from `body("[<-.data.frame")` if you feel inclined, but it's not a pleasant function to read through. What you are asking about will be the case where `i` and `j` are both missing in the function call.

Comment: My apologies to all the kind folks taking interest in my question. Been unable able to give your suggestions enough time because of some unforeseens . Will look up and post what I find as soon as I can. -R.S.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an intentional and documented feature. As joran mentioned, the documentation page "Extract" includes this in the "Atomic Vectors" section:

> An empty index selects all values: this is most often used to replace all the entries but keep the attributes.

However, in the case of recursive objects (`data.frames` or `lists`, for example), the attributes are only kept for the subsetted object. Its parts don't get such protection.

Here's an example:

```
animals <- factor(c('cat', 'dog', 'fish'))
df_factor <- data.frame(x = animals)
rownames(df_factor) <- c('meow', 'bark', 'blub')
str(df_factor)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
#   $ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "cat","dog","fish": 1 2 3

df_factor[] <- 'cat'
str(df_factor)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
#   $ x: chr  "cat" "cat" "cat"
rownames(df_factor)
# [1] "meow" "bark" "blub"
```

`df_factor` kept its `rownames` attribute, but the `x` column is just the character vector used in the assignment instead of a factor. We can keep the class and levels of `x` by specifically replacing its values:

```
df_factor <- data.frame(x = animals)
df_factor$x[] <- 'cat'
str(df_factor)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
#   $ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "cat","dog","fish": 1 1 1
```

So replacement with empty subsetting is very safe for vectors, matrices, and arrays, because their elements can't have their own attributes. But it requires some care when dealing with list-like objects.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. I had seen that line from documented that you had highlighted and it seemed to suggest (to me) that the operation was very safe , but I had examples to the contrary. The remark  that `sub-parts will get no such protection`  puts  the finger on it, and the example deals with it.  The only other point I would like to add (which is actually inherent in this reply ) is that this operation is reliable only when LHS is more complex than RHS