# Convert all columns to characters in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider a data.frame with a mix of data types.

For a weird purpose, a user needs to convert all columns to characters.
How is it best done? A tidyverse attempt at solution is this:

```
map(mtcars,as.character) %>% map_df(as.list) %>% View()
c2<-map(mtcars,as.character) %>% map_df(as.list)
```

when I call `str(c2)` it should say a tibble or data.frame with all characters.

The other option would be some parameter settings for `write.csv()` or in `write_csv()` to achieve the same thing in the resulting file output.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**EDIT: 2021-03-01**

Beginning with dplyr 1.0.0, the `_all()` function variants are deprecated. The new way to accomplish this is using the new `across()` function.

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character))
```

With `across()`, we choose the set of columns we want to modify using [tidyselect helpers](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/select_helpers.html) (here we use `everything()` to choose all columns), and then specify the function we want to apply to each of the selected columns. In this case, that is `as.character()`.

**Original answer:**

You can also use `dplyr::mutate_all`.

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  mutate_all(as.character)
```

Comment: Note that "superseded" and "deprecated" are different (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lifecycle/vignettes/stages.html). Superseded doesn't get new updates and suggests that the new way has advantages, but that doesn't mean better for every situation.

Answer (score 37):

**In base R:**

```
x[] <- lapply(x, as.character)
```

This converts the columns to character class in place, retaining the data.frame's attributes.  A call to `data.frame()` would cause them to be lost.

**Attribute preservation using dplyr:**  Attributes seem to be preserved during `dplyr::mutate(across(everything(), as.character))`.  Previously they were destroyed by `dplyr::mutate_all`.

**Example**

```
x <- mtcars
attr(x, "example") <- "1"
```

In the second case below, the `example` attribute is retained:

```
# Destroys attributes

data.frame(lapply(x, as.character)) %>%
  attributes()

# Preserves attributes

x[] <- lapply(x, as.character)
attributes(x)
```

Comment: I think this can be simplified to `x[] <- lapply(x, as.character)`

Comment: This is the best answer IMO, on the basis that it preserves attributes of the data.frame. @Sam is there any reason not to simply as sindri suggests?

Comment: good call, I have updated the answer with this simpler command

Comment: @sindri_baldur Could you please clarify how `x[] <- lapply(x, as.character)` works? I mean, `lapply` accepts list and returns list. How here `lapply` is working with data frame?

Comment: @vasili111 Adding `[]` forces it to not lose its attributes (`data.frame` in this case  (which is built on a special type of lists)).

Comment: @sindri_baldur Thank you.

Comment: @vasili111 See also [Assignment to empty index (empty square brackets) on LHS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191623/assignment-to-empty-index-empty-square-brackets-x-on-lhs)

Answer (score 4):

This might work, but not sure if it's the best.

```
df = data.frame(lapply(mtcars, as.character))
str(df)
```

Answer (score 4):

Most efficient way using `data.table`-

```
data.table::setDT(mtcars)
mtcars[, (colnames(mtcars)) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = colnames(mtcars)]
```

**Note:** You can use this to convert few columns of a `data table` to your desired column type.

If we want to convert all columns to character then we can also do something like this-

```
to_col_type <- function(col_names,type){
            get(paste0("as.", type))(dt[[col_names]])
            }
mtcars<- rbindlist(list(Map(to_col_type ,colnames(mtcars),"character")))
```

Answer (score 2):

`mutate_all` in the accepted answer is [superseded](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html#section-superseded).

You can use `mutate()` function with [`across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html):

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character))
```

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my answer to reflect the updated dplyr syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be using the [`map_df`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) function from the `purrr` package like this:

```r
library(purrr)
map_df(mtcars, as.character)
#> # A tibble: 32 × 11
#>    mpg   cyl   disp  hp    drat  wt    qsec  vs    am    gear  carb 
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 21    6     160   110   3.9   2.62  16.46 0     1     4     4    
#>  2 21    6     160   110   3.9   2.875 17.02 0     1     4     4    
#>  3 22.8  4     108   93    3.85  2.32  18.61 1     1     4     1    
#>  4 21.4  6     258   110   3.08  3.215 19.44 1     0     3     1    
#>  5 18.7  8     360   175   3.15  3.44  17.02 0     0     3     2    
#>  6 18.1  6     225   105   2.76  3.46  20.22 1     0     3     1    
#>  7 14.3  8     360   245   3.21  3.57  15.84 0     0     3     4    
#>  8 24.4  4     146.7 62    3.69  3.19  20    1     0     4     2    
#>  9 22.8  4     140.8 95    3.92  3.15  22.9  1     0     4     2    
#> 10 19.2  6     167.6 123   3.92  3.44  18.3  1     0     4     4    
#> # … with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you want to have the output to be a `data.frame`, you could add `as.data.frame` to your pipe.