# How to scale data frame but retain type of dataframe?

Tags: r

Built-in function scale will standardize each column of dataframe,but it will transformation original data frame into matrix.How to fix it?What if I just want to standardize only some columns?

Comment: Can you use dput to provide some data and the code that you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's kind of two questions here. The first, how to insert into a `data.frame` without losing the `data.frame` structure. In this case use `[<-` like so:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=10:12, c=20:22)
df[] <- scale(df)
df
#   a  b  c
#1 -1 -1 -1
#2  0  0  0
#3  1  1  1
```

This is covered in a lot more detail here: [R: Easy assignments with empty square brackets? x[]<-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191623/r-easy-assignments-with-empty-square-brackets-x)

The second question is how to update a subset of a `data.frame`. Again, use `[<-` but this time match the selections on the left and right sides of the `<-` :

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=10:12, c=20:22)
df[1:2] <- scale(df[1:2])
df
#   a  b  c
#1 -1 -1 20
#2  0  0 21
#3  1  1 22
```