# How do I preserve the data frame structure after using paste()?

Tags: r

```
> list1<-list("A1","A2")
> str(list1)
    List of 2
     $ : chr "A1"
     $ : chr "A2"
> list1<-paste(list1,"example",sep=" ")
> str(list1)
 chr [1:2] "A1 example" "A2 example"
```

I had wanted to preserve the list structure, but it seems like pasting new values into the list changes it.

How should I go about writing the code without affect the structure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[]` to preserve the structure.

```
list1[] <- paste(list1,"example")

str(list1)
#List of 2
# $ : chr "A1 example"
# $ : chr "A2 example"
```

Comment: Word of caution though: "So replacement with empty subsetting is very safe for vectors, matrices, and arrays, because their elements can't have their own attributes. _But it requires some care when dealing with list-like objects_", from [Assignment to empty index on LHS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191623/assignment-to-empty-index-empty-square-brackets-x-on-lhs/45104831#45104831)