# what does bracket [] do when assigning lapply output

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I have a variable `v` as follows:

```
> head(v)
    C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   C6   C7   C8   C9  C10
1 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2
2 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1
3 0.p1 0.p1 0.p1 0.p1 0.p1 0.p1 0.p1 0.p1 0.p1 0.p1
4 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1 0.m1
5 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2
6 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2 0.m2
```

I want to get ride of the trailing ".m1" for each element of the dataframe.

When I do lapply, it gives me a list of C1, C2, ...

```
> lapply(v, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("\\..*", "", x))) %>% str
List of 10
 $ C1 : num [1:40000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ C2 : num [1:40000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ C3 : num [1:40000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ C4 : num [1:40000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ C5 : num [1:40000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ C6 : num [1:40000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ C7 : num [1:40000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ C8 : num [1:40000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ C9 : num [1:40000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ C10: num [1:40000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

However, I want a dataframe with the dimension staying the same, so I do the following and it works

```
> v[]=lapply(v, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("\\..*", "", x)))
> head(v)
  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

Is [] needed to change each element of v? Is there a better way to code this? Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191623/assignment-to-empty-index-empty-square-brackets-x-on-lhs; "An empty index selects all values: this is most often used to replace all the entries but keep the attributes."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `v` is a `data.frame`, which is essentially (but not perfectly) a `list` where all elements are named and are the same lengths.
- `lapply` always returns a `list`. Period. It doesn't care that its input came from a `frame`, that is not its intent.
- `v = lapply(..)` replaces the object reference named `"v"` with the new object, which is (as stated above) a `list`. However ...
- `v[] = lapply(..)` replaces the *contents* of `v` with the return from `lapply(..)` without changing the class and attributes of `v`, so it remains a frame with the list-contents returned by `lapply`. Realize that the same effect can be had with `v = data.frame(lapply(..))`.

Comment: If you run `identical(v, v[])` it will return `TRUE`. So what is the `[` function doing with respect to the lapply call? If this its own separate question instead of an elaboration on the above answer, I am happy to make a new post

Comment: Regardless of what `v` contains (list versus frame), `[]` changes neither its contents nor its class, so they will be identical, but this is regardless of the reassignment in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking what other, possibly better, method there would be, here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)  
df %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(str_extract(., "\\d+"))))
  C1 C2 C3
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0
3  0  0  0
```

Instead of `gsub`(or better `sub`, as we're dealing with a single match per string), as in your solution (which is of course possible too but slightly more verbose), we're using here `str_extract` to extract the string-first `d`igit(s).

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  C1 = c("0.m1", "0.p2", "0.p1"),
  C2 = c("0.p1", "0.p0", "0.p1"),
  C3 = c("0.m2", "0.p1", "0.p1")
)
```